# Bootstrap + Rails 6 + webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal, webpacker

Gettings this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
```

Now, here is my application hierarchy:

```
- app
  - assets
    - images
    - stylesheets
  - controllers
  - javascript
    - packs
      - theme.js
      - bootstrap_custom.js
    - stylesheets
      - bootstrap_custom.scss
      - theme.scss
```

Here is my theme.js:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
import '../stylesheets/theme';

import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
// import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';

import './bootstrap_custom.js'

import 'jquery-storage-api/jquery.storageapi';
import 'tether/dist/js/tether';
// import 'underscore/underscore';
import _ from 'underscore/underscore';
import 'pace/pace';

import uiLoad from "theme/ui-load";

window._ = _;
window.$ = jQuery;
```

here is my theme.scss:

```
$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import 'tether/dist/css/tether';
@import './bootstrap_custom.scss';
```

Now, in bootstrap_custom.js, I have imported modal js:

```
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/alert'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/button'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/carousel'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/collapse'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/index'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/popover'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tab'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/toast'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip'
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/util'
```

and similarly for bootstrap_custom.scss:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_root.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_reboot.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_type.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_alert.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_badge';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_breadcrumb';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_button-group';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_buttons';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_buttons.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_card.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_carousel.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_close.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_code.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_custom-forms.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_dropdown.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_forms.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_images.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_input-group.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_jumbotron.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_list-group.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_media.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_modal.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_nav.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_navbar.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_pagination.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_popover.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_print.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_progress.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_spinners.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_tables.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_toasts.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_tooltip.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_transitions.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_utilities.scss';
```

I don't think there is any issue in order of bootstrap modal js as jquery is already defined in wepacker environment.js

Comment: Is this part present in your own code anywhere : "`).modal`"

Comment: Be sure you have `import 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal'` again in the file you are calling the `modal` function.